# Run perf with an MPI application

Tags: linux, performance, parallel-processing

`perf` is a performance analysis tool which can report hardware and software events. I am trying to run it with an MPI application in order to learn how much time the application spends within each core on data transfers and compute operations.

Normally, I would run my application with

```
mpirun -np $NUMBER_OF_CORES app_name
```

And it would spawn on several cores or possibly several nodes. Is it possible to add `perf` on top? I've tried

```
perf stat mpirun -np $NUMBER_OF_CORES app_name
```

But the output for this looks like some sort of aggregate of mpirun. Is there a way to collect perf type data from each core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
mpirun -np $NUMBER_OF_CORES ./myscript.sh
```

might work with myscript.sh containing:

```
#! /bin/bash
perf stat app_name %*
```

You should add some parameter to the perf call to produce differently named result files.

Answer (score 1):

`perf` can follow spawned child processes. To profile the MPI processes located on the same node, you can simply do

```
perf stat mpiexec -n 2 ./my-mpi-app
```

You can use `perf record` as well. It will create a single `perf.data` file containing the profiling information for all the local MPI processes. However, this won't allow you to profile individual MPI ranks.

To find out information about individual mpi ranks, you need to run

```
mpiexec -n 2 perf stat ./my-mpi-app
```

This will profile the individual ranks and will also work across multiple nodes. However, this does not work with some `perf` commands such as `perf record`.